# What do these statements in a module script achieve?

Tags: python, import, module

First sorry for the vague question. But I am trying to understand a python program and encounter some code I have never seen before. Specifically, in `ModuleA.py`, we have

```
def human_size(num, precision = 3):
    return human_num(num, precision + 'B')
```

in `ModuleB.py`,

```
from .ModuleA import human_size

human_size # what is this line trying to achieve?
```

There are other similar lines in the code.

Update: the code base is from https://github.com/houtianze/bypy

ModuleA → `bypy/printer_util.py`

ModuleB → `bypy/util.py`

Comment: If it's literally just `human_size`, then it's pointless, but it's likely you omitted some important context.

Comment: I am just posting the code snippets which I don't understand. The whole code base is here https://github.com/houtianze/bypy.

Comment: Yup, that's just pointless. Maybe they had a weird linter config that complained about unused imports without those lines, but didn't complain about code that does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

change from .ModuleA for ModuleA, if the module is in other directory write ./path/nameModule